# How to "put everything together" in Android app?

Tags: android, application-state

Im learning Android and writing my first big application. It is client-server app and it uses Google login mechanism and will use Facebook login in future.

I wrote fundamental parts of app, like "Login with Google", connection with web service, few Activities that do something.

**Now I have problem: how to put everything together?**

Where should I store "application state", like current user e-mail or information if he is logged in or not? Now such data is inside "ActivityGoogleLogin" class which is destroyed after user logs in.

Another problem - lets say I have something like "MyHttpClient" object and I want to access it from every Activity. How to deal with this?

In C# (which is my background) I just create static class that holds my application state and it's easy to access it from everywhere.

I know that in Java something like **"singleton" exists, but I don't know how to use it**. It seems to be more complicated than C# static class where I don't even have to write accessors and I don't have to initialize it.

Comment: For storing simple information, you can use `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: You can make a class with static parameters in Java. I'm not familiar with C# but I'm sure it's the same. The class itself can't be static, only its members but it works the same way.

Comment: @Barodapride While this is possible, it's not very OO friendly. And it isn't persistent.

Comment: When I have class with static parameters - do I have to instantinate it? Where should I initialize it? In main Activity?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I need to store complicated objects, not simple information.

Comment: @Kamil "email" and "logged in" doesn't sound like complicated objects.

Comment: I suggest you read [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to put there whole MyHttpClient class there.

Comment: @Kamil What is `MyHttpClient`? Can you post some code to show what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

> Another problem - lets say I have something like "MyHttpClient" object and I want to access it from every Activity.

If every `Activity` needs a HTTP connection, they should each create their own instance of `MyHttpClient` rather than trying to share the same object between different activities.